# Will Ubuntu run on an AMD 6 core processor and ATI graphics card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, graphics

I'm building a computer with AMD 6 core  process  and its respective motherboard takes ATI or Nvidia as graphic cards, Ram 32GB, HDD 2x3TB, usb2.0/3.0 ports. I want to know if I'm correct by saying that Ubuntu will have not problem running by using the processor,ram,motherboard,hdds?

My other concern is the graphic card, I'm planning to set my computer with three monitors and my 60" TV, so What video card you guys recommend for this purpose.

If you have advises in how to build a computer for Ubuntu also comment.

- AMD FX-6300 FX-Series Six-Core Processor Black Edition
- G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 32GB (4 x 8GB) 240-Pin SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800)
- ASUS DDR3 1800 AM3 Motherboards Sabertooth 990FX/GEN3 R2.0 
  GeForce GTX 670 as my graphic card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Yes it will work.

**Longer Answer:** There might be some extra effort required (but likely not and it will just work)

Your question is too broad. People have got ubuntu to run on lots of hardware including the nexus tablets, washing machines and toasters (ok, I made up the last two examples). So an AMD6 processor is quite likely to be possible [as you can see here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96280/can-ubuntu-or-server-run-a-64-core-4x16-server-one-motherboard)`

If you need specific advice you need to give the model of the motherboard and all the peripherals you are interested in. If you buy standard hardware as you do from the sounds of it there won't be any problems.

---

**EDIT** after you supplied details of your hardware.

The memory doesn't matter since if it works for one OS on your hardware it will likely work for others. Almost the same is true for your processor. I had a quick look at the user comments on NewEgg for your board. There seems to be nothing remarkable, some claim it's fine. One had problems with the network card but got around it by using a separate NIC.

In summary, you'll likely be fine.

Comment: AMD FX-6300 FX-Series Six-Core Processor Black Edition

Comment: G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 32GB (4 x 8GB) 240-Pin SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800)

Comment: ASUS DDR3 1800 AM3 Motherboards Sabertooth 990FX/GEN3 R2.0